# react native listview scroll to a specific section

Tags: javascript, listview, react-native, react-native-listview, react-native-scrollview

i have a ListView component that render calendar with list of events. data structure is:

```
const data = {
'092016':[{id:1,title:'event1'},{id:1,title:'event1'}],
'102016':[{id:1,title:'event1'},{id:1,title:'event1'}],
}
```

ListView code:

```
 <ListView
            style={{flex:1}}
            dataSource={this.state.posts}
            pageSize={3}
            onEndReachedThreshold={200}
            enableEmptySections={true}
            keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
            renderRow={(event) => <Text>{event.title}</Text>}
            renderSectionHeader={(data,month)=><Text>{month}</Text>}
          />

  ....dataSource = new ListView.DataSource({
rowHasChanged           : (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
sectionHeaderHasChanged : (s1, s2) => s1 !== s2});
 ... on component mount
    this.setState({posts:dataSource.cloneWithRowsAndSections(data)});
```

this works as expected.

now i want to be able to scroll to a specific section in js. how can i achive this ?

something like

```
scrollTo('102016') // scroll to section with id='102016'
```

Comment: ever find a solution to this?